# load parameters from a file in Python

Tags: python, file, serialization, input

I am writing a Python class to model a process and I want to initialized the parameters from a file, say `'input.dat'`. The format of the input file looks like this.

`'input.dat'` file:

```
Z0: 0 0
k: 0.1
g: 1
Delta: 20
t_end: 300
```

The code I wrote is the following. It works but appears redundant and inflexible. Is there a better way to do the job? Such as a loop to do readline() and then match the keyword?

```
def load(self,filename="input.dat"):
    FILE = open(filename)
    s = FILE.readline().split()
    if len(s) is 3:
        self.z0 = [float(s[1]),float(s[2])] # initial state
    s = FILE.readline().split()
    if len(s) is 2:
        self.k = float(s[1])    # kappa
    s = FILE.readline().split()
    if len(s) is 2:
        self.g = float(s[1])
    s = FILE.readline().split()
    if len(s) is 2:
        self.D = float(s[1])    #  Delta
    s = FILE.readline().split()
    if len(s) is 2:
        self.T = float(s[1])    # end time
```

Comment: I find initial formatting beats parsing any day.  And in practice have changed formatting to better interface with python.  If you can change your input.dat, to look more like a pretty-printed python dictionary, you can suck in the entire glob and run eval() on it.  so add brackets at the beginning and end, some quotes around strings, and you will be much happier!

Comment: @pyInTheSky: Yech. Don't `eval()` a config file. Use something safe, like `JSON` or `ConfigParser`.

Comment: @Tim, Python-based config files are *very* useful in certain cases, see my answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8527168/68707

Comment: @Tim certainly json works too.  And to nos :: json format and python dict format are pretty much the same, so you can import json and do json.loads(file.read()) and have quick success in getting what you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- If you are open to some other kind of file where you can keep your parameters, I would suggest you to use a [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) file.
- The Python library is [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/). [This](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) is how you can easily use it with Python.
- For a better introduction, look at this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML.
- The benefit is you can read the parameter values as lists or maps.
- You would love it!

Comment: Why not JSON or .INI, which are both built into Python's stdlib? Or "import" (see my answer).

Comment: @benhoyt, I guess its more about convenience, I am sure your solution works too :)

Answer (score 40):

Assuming the params are coming from a safe place (made by you or users, not the internet), just make the parameters file a Python file, `params.py`:

```
Z0 = (0, 0)
k = 0.1
g = 1
Delta = 20
t_end = 300
```

Then in your code all you need is:

```
import params
fancy_calculation(10, k=params.k, delta=params.Delta)
```

The beauty of this is two-fold: 1) simplicity, and 2) you can use the power of Python in your parameter descriptions -- particularly useful here, for example:

```
k = 0.1
Delta = 20
g = 3 * k + Delta
```

Alternatively, you could use Python's built-in [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) or [ConfigParser .INI parser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) modules.

Comment: however, can one then have multiple parameters files, and the specific parameter.py be given from command line?

Comment: @fabiob You can -- you'd use something like [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to import a file with a name generated at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
def load(self, filename="input.dat"):
    d = {"Z0": "z0", "k": "k", "g": "g", "Delta": "D", "t_end": "T"}
    FILE = open(filename)
    for line in FILE:
        name, value = line.split(":")
        value = value.strip()
        if " " in value:
            value = map(float, value.split())
        else:
            value = float(value)
        setattr(self, d[name], value)
```

Proof that it works:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> load(a)
>>> a.__dict__
{'k': 0.10000000000000001, 'z0': [0.0, 0.0], 'D': 20.0, 'g': 1.0, 'T': 300.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, in Python you can create object attributes dynamically "[on the fly](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+fly)". That means you could do something like the following to create `Params` objects as they're read-in. I've tried to make the code as data-driven as possible, so relatively flexible.

```
# maps label to attribute name and types
label_attr_map = {
       "Z0:": ["z0", float, float],
        "k:": [ "k", float],
        "g:": [ "g", float],
    "Delta:": [ "D", float],
    "t_end:": [ "T", float]
}

class Params(object):
    def __init__(self, input_file_name):
        with open(input_file_name, 'r') as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                row = line.split()
                label = row[0]
                data = row[1:]  # rest of row is data list

                attr = label_attr_map[label][0]
                datatypes = label_attr_map[label][1:]

                values = [(datatypes[i](data[i])) for i in range(len(data))]
                self.__dict__[attr] = values if len(values) > 1 else values[0]


params = Params('input.dat')
print 'params.z0:', params.z0
print 'params.k:', params.k
print 'params.g:', params.g
print 'params.D:', params.D
print 'params.T:', params.T
```

Output:

```
params.z0: [0.0, 0.0]
params.k: 0.1
params.g: 1.0
params.D: 20.0
params.T: 300.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might give you what you need:

```
def load(self,filename='input.dat'):
    with open(filename) as fh:
        for line in fh:
           s = line.split()
           if len(s) == 2:
               setattr(self,s[1],s[2])
           elif len(s) == 3:
               setattr(self,s[1],s[2:])
```

I also didn't include any error checking, but [setattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def load(self,filename="input.dat"):

    # maps names to number of fields they need
    # only necessary for variables with more than 1 field
    argmap = dict(Z0=2)

    # maps config file names to their attribute names on the object
    # if name is the same both places, no need
    namemap = dict(Z0="z0", Delta="D", t_end="T")

    with open(filename) as FILE:
        for line in FILE:
            s = line.split()
            var = s[0].rstrip(":")
            try:
                val = [float(x) for x in s[1:]]
            except ValueError:
                continue
            if len(val) == varmap.get(var, 1):
               if len(val) == 1:
                   val = val[0]
               setattr(self, namemap.get(var, var), val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python objects have a built-in `__dict__` member.  You can modify it, and then refer to properties as `obj.key`.

```
class Data(object):
  def __init__(self, path='infile.dat'):
    with open(path, 'r') as fo:
      for line in fo.readlines():
        if len(line) < 2: continue

        parts = [s.strip(' :\n') for s in line.split(' ', 1)]
        numbers = [float(s) for s in parts[1].split()]

        # This is optional... do you want single values to be stored in lists?
        if len(numbers) == 1: numbers = numbers[0]
        self.__dict__[parts[0]] = numbers
        # print parts  -- debug

obj = Data('infile.dat')
print obj.g
print obj.Delta
print obj.Z0
```

At the end of this, we print out a few of the keys.  Here's the output of those.

```
1.0
20.0
[0.0, 0.0]
```

For consistency, you can remove the line marked "optional" in my code, and have all objects in lists -- regardless of how many elements they have.  That will make using them quite a bit easier, because you never have to worry about `obj.g[0]` returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one

```
def splitstrip(s):
    return s.split(':')[1].strip()

with open('input.dat','r') as f:
    a.z0 = [float(x) for x in splitstrip(f.readline()).split(' ')]
    a.k, a.g, a.D, a.T = tuple([float(splitstrip(x)) for x in f.read().rstrip().split('\n')])
```

;)